# Keyboard doesn't work during boot

Tags: boot, kernel, keyboard

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. During boot, I am asked to enter my password to decrypt my disk. However, neither my keyboard nor my mouse work, so I can't enter my password. I have attempted to enter my password even though nothing has shown up on the screen and hitting enter, to no avail.

However, when I turn the computer off at this point, and reboot it, I now how the option to select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu". I select to boot into the kernel "4.4.0-31-generic", and then it works. However, when I select to boot into "4.4.0-59-generic", I cannot use my keyboard or mouse.

Other than being annoying, this isn't a huge problem, but I worry that the linux kernel "4.4.0-31" will get autoremoved by accident, and I'll be locked out of my computer.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is this a wireless keyboard/mouse... like a Logitech? They sometimes have problems if the machine is not fully booted. Otherwise, you might check your BIOS setting for the USB ports, and make sure that legacy is enabled.

Comment: No, both are wired.

Comment: Did you look for a BIOS USB setting for legacy support?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Neither the keyboard or mouse are old. https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-3-Button-Wired-Mouse-Black/dp/B005EJH6RW/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1485192321&sr=8-2&keywords=amazonbasics+mouse, https://www.amazon.com/Freestyle2-Ergonomic-Keyboard-Standard-Separation/dp/B00CMALD3E/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1485192346&sr=8-2&keywords=kinesis+keyboard

Comment: At power up/boot time, hit the key that brings up your BIOS... usually it'll tell you on the splash screen what that key is... maybe F2, or Esc, or Del. Once there, look through the BIOS settings for USB settings... there's probably only one... and there's usually a pop up choice for that setting... and you should try legacy... or USB 2/3 support... etc. Be sure to save your setting when you leave the BIOS. Don't change anything else. You could also try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD 16.10 and see if the problem still exists.