# Keyboard not working after software update today

Tags: keyboard

On Ubuntu 18.04 desktop 64 bit, wireless keyboard has stopped working today. I have tried a wired keyboard with same result. All software is fully up to date. Help please!
PS I'm reduced to using the on screen keyboard.

Comment: Can try this link.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032710/keyboard-not-working-after-login-after-update-to-18-04?rq=1  also list computer specs and kernel version in your question.

Comment: Tried doing commands in that link. Kernel:

Comment: Try dropping down a kernel or two.  Recent 5.4 kernels have been causing trouble with laptop keyboards, but externals still work.  You seem to have externals not working.  Have you tried changing USB ports?  Do keyboards work with bios/grub and stop after loading?

Comment: did commands in link. kernel given by john@JohnPC:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-117-generic. N3050 Celeron 8GB processor shown by sysinfo. lsusb shows keyboard:  Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1241:1503 Belkin Keyboard

Comment: standard keyboard i.e. laptop. tried changing usb ports. keyboards do not work during booting. so how change kernel?

Comment: Can try this.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/874668/keyboard-doesnt-work-during-boot

Comment: crip659's link solved the problem. Wireless keyboard did not work to get into BIOS but wired keyboard did. All USB ports were on but USB Legacy was off. So I set USB Legacy to on and saved BIOS settings & let it boot. Both wired & wireless keyboards then worked OK. I assume that the latest kernel update must now require USB Legacy set on for both wired & wireless keyboards.